# Making an button-activated animated tour in d3

Tags: d3.js, geo, cartodb

I'm trying to make a button-activated d3 zoom tour through three Northeastern US points, but am having a hard time getting the data to show up visually (it shows in the console, though). I'm a beginning user and can usually solve things, but this is over my head.

Here are the an example that comes close to what I'm trying to do:

Zooms between different spots in US:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6242308

The example doesn't style the data, uses TopoJSON and also uses canvas to do the zooming calls. I'm trying to do the zoom with GeoJSON(so I can link to a CartoDB table), and style it.

I've gone through a lot to make both of those things happen and am running out of successes. Right now it comes up blank and has been. I can see the data live, but can't change the styling.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm sure it's something simple, but need a nudge.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
canvas{
color: 'blue';

}
    path.state {
      color: 'red';
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    stateMap; 

var sf = [-122.417, 37.775],
    ny = [-74.0064, 40.7142];

var scale,
    translate,
    visibleArea, // minimum area threshold for points inside viewport
    invisibleArea; // minimum area threshold for points outside viewport

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .size([width, height])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .translate([width/2, height/2])
    .scale(500);

 var canvas = d3.select("body").append("canvas")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(simplify)
    .context(context);

stateMap = d3.json("http://linepointpath.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?format=GeoJSON&q=SELECT * FROM GRAPHstates", function(error, stateMap) {
  console.log(stateMap)
  canvas
      svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(stateMap.feature)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "state")
           .attr("d", path)
      .call(zoomTo(sf, 4).event)
    .transition()
      .duration(60 * 1000 / 89 * 2)
      .each(jump);
});

var simplify = d3.geo.transform({
  point: function(x, y, z) {
    if (z < visibleArea) return;
    x = x * scale + translate[0];
    y = y * scale + translate[1];
    if (x >= -10 && x <= width + 10 && y >= -10 && y <= height + 10 || z >= invisibleArea)     this.stream.point(x, y);
  }
});

function zoomTo(location, scale) {
  var point = projection(location);
  return zoom
      .translate([width / 2 - point[0] * scale, height / 2 - point[1] * scale])
      .scale(scale);
}

function zoomed(d) {
  translate = zoom.translate();
  scale = zoom.scale();
  visibleArea = 1 / scale / scale;
  invisibleArea = 200 * visibleArea;
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  context.beginPath();
  path(d);
  context.stroke();
}

function jump() {
  var t = d3.select(this);
  (function repeat() {
    t = t.transition()
   .call(zoomTo(ny, 6).event)
  .transition()
    .call(zoomTo(sf, 4).event)
    .each("end", repeat);
  })();
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you get the map to appear? That'd be the first step. Get it to appear with your projection settings. Then work on the other pieces..

Comment: You have a few silly syntax errors: a `console.log` statement in the middle of a chain, you have stateMap.feature instead of stateMap.feature**s**.  You also seem to be mixing a canvas approach and svg together.  I'd take a step back, get the basics working then build on it.  Cutting/pasting code together haphazardly isn't going to work.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I cannot get the map to appear, no. I'll work in that direction first. 

I'll clean up those few bits to get them out of the way. Sorry about that. 

As for the svg/canvas mix, that's what I'm trying to solve. I have plenty of versions that work great with SVG, but can't get the zoom to function as it does in the canvas example. I assumed I had to use svg with canvas. Is there another way I'm missing? I haven't actually been cutting and pasting bits of code. I've taken that initial example and modified it where I thought I was doing right. Perhaps I just made a mess.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the larger issue is that you're using a [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) when the example you're going by is using a [TopoJSON](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki). The differences between the two are likely causing problems with how the `path`s are being rendered.

Another problem you're running into is that with a `canvas`, the function calls are different. You're using the normal `svg` function calls to append an SVG, bind the data, and they style it. With `canvas`, you interact with the elements through the [canvas `context` object](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-element/). This has a different syntax and usage than the standard SVG object you're trying to use in your code. If you follow [this tutorial](http://bocoup.com/weblog/d3js-and-canvas/) you'll notice she doesn't call any of the SVG functions but instead uses the `context` API to draw and style the `canvas` elements. Be sure to look at [the working example of the code](http://jsfiddle.net/iros/2jhCm/).

In your case, this means your code here:

```
svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(stateMap.feature)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "state")
       .attr("d", path)
  .call(zoomTo(sf, 4).event)
.transition()
  .duration(60 * 1000 / 89 * 2)
```

Is unnecessary and not doing anything for you. The code that generates the path is embedded in the `zoomed()` function using the `context` object:

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
context.beginPath();
path(d);
context.stroke();
```

It's using the `context` functions to create the objects you're trying to show. There are a chain of function calls that generate this behavior and you'll need to break down the chain to make sure you're getting what you want at each step.

If you want to use the GeoJSON start with just getting the map to display and then applying the zoom functionality. It'll probably make your life a lot easier in the end to iteratively build the visualization you want.

For more information on the difference between `canvas` and `svg` with D3, including examples of doing the same operation with each, checkout this [blogpost](http://geoexamples.blogspot.com/2013/02/mapping-with-d3js-canvas-or-svg.html) and good luck with the project.